# Not getting the updated value of an rxjs BehaviorSubject in a component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on this photo editor app where changes are auto-saved in the db. Now I'm trying to add a toast that would display when the editor data is saved to db successfully. So I'm using RxJS's `BehaviorSubject` to achieve that.

Please note that the editor changes are first sent to a service called `DataProcessService` where it is processed and then an API call is made which is in another service. Also in `DataProcessService`, I have set up the logic for the BehaviorSubject.

This is how the code in DataProcessService looks like now:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
class DataProcessService {

  private toast = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>( false );
  currentToastState = this.toast.asObservable()

  private constructor( private apiService: ApiService ) {}

  changeToastState( state: boolean ): void {
     this.toast.next( state );
  }

  process( data ) { 
   
    // got rid of data processing for simplicity
    
    this.apiService.postData( data )
      .then( response => {
        console.log('Success');
        this.changeToastState( true );
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
      })
  }

}
```

This is the PhotoEditorComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'editor-page',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

class PhotoEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('toast');

  toast: ToastComponent;
  isToast: boolean;

  private constructor( private dataProcessService: DataProcessService ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dataProcessService.currentToastState.subscribe( state => {
      this.isToast = state;
    });

    console.log( 'Log 1: ', this.isToast );

    if ( this.isToast ) {
      console.log( 'Log 2: ', this.isToast );
      this.successMessage = 'Saved successfully!;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      this.toast.show();
      this.dataProcessService.changeToastState( false );
    }

  }

}
```

Please note that `Log 1` is `false` when I refresh the page. And when there is a change in the editor it does not turn it to `true` or whatsoever. `Log 2` never fires```

Comment: The entire this.isToast if, should be inside the subscribe

Comment: Post it as an answer

Comment: @MikeOne Is it necessary to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy?

Comment: Yes! Always unsubscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this 'if block' should be in subscribe block I guess!

```
if ( this.isToast ) {
      console.log( 'Log 2: ', this.isToast );
      this.successMessage = 'Saved successfully!;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      this.toast.show();
      this.dataProcessService.changeToastState( false );
    }
```

Comment: Yeah someone commented this solution. I'm waiting for him to post it as an answer. If he doesn't respond, will choose your one.

Comment: It’s no problem. Not in a position to post a proper answer (on the road with mobile only). Feel free to accept this answer.